# SQL - Calculation with Union All and Join

Tags: mysql, join, union-all

I have 3 SQL tables, one for each vendor.  All the tables have 3 identical columns: (id), (spend), and (date).  (id) stands for product id.  (spend) is how much they spent on the product.  And (date) of the transaction.

Thanks to stackoverflow, I was able to sort by the total spent on each product (id) including all tables.  Here is the UNION ALL statement that works:

```
SELECT id, SUM(spend) as total
                    FROM (
                        SELECT id, spend, date 
                        FROM vendor1 
                        WHERE date BETWEEN '$dateStart' AND '$dateEnd'
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT id, spend, date 
                        FROM vendor2
                        WHERE date BETWEEN '$dateStart' AND '$dateEnd'
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT id, spend, date 
                        FROM vendor3
                        WHERE date BETWEEN '$dateStart' AND '$dateEnd'
                    ) as SpendTotal  
                    GROUP BY id 
                    ORDER BY total DESC
```

Now I would like to incorporate a new table (revTbl) in the SQL formula that lists revenue earned from each product (id).  This 4th table has the same column labeled (id) as the 3 mentioned above.  It also has the same (date) column.  However, this table has a different column named (rev).

I would like to write a SQL statement that sorts by the SUM(rev)-SUM(spend).  I tried including it as UNION ALL but no luck, and after reading about UNION ALL I understand why.  I'm guessing I need to incorporate a JOIN statement, but not sure where to begin.  Please help me write the proper SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two sub-queries and join them by Id. Something like this:

```
Select rev.id, total_rev - rev_total as result from 
      (SELECT id, SUM(rev) as total_rev
                    FROM rev
                    GROUP BY id) as rev
join  (SELECT id, SUM(spend) as spend_total
                    FROM (
                        SELECT id, spend, at 
                        FROM vendor1 
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT id, spend, at
                        FROM vendor2
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT id, spend, at
                        FROM vendor3
                    ) as SpendTotal
                    GROUP BY id) as spend on spend.id = rev.id order by result;
```

I removed the conditions from your sql for simplicity. Also changed the "date" column names to "at" because date is sql data type as far as I recall.

Comment: Did you get an error? Or it returned unexpected results?